# How can I use gcc-go and go together in archlinux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm trying to test performance of `gccgo` and default go compiler (`gc`).

But when I install package `go` and `gcc-go` with pacman, it complains about conflicts.

```
> sudo pacman -S go
> sudo pacman -S gcc-go
```

I just want to create two kind of binaries, one uses gc and other one uses gccgo.

Is there any way to use them together?

Answer (score 0):

Simply install `gcc-go` and build with either `go build -compiler gccgo ...` or `go build -v -compiler gc ...`
The package `gc`is independent from `gcc-go`.